# one viewport not working in css

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have four viewports set up for a site, as follows:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 769px) {
 ...
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
...
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
...
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
...
}
```

and have declared the viewport meta with meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"

All the code works fine except for 320px.  Even when I am just resizing in the browser, when the width is 320px the css is for the 480px width.

Comment: may be the priority issue.......? Post the relevant css...

Comment: may be some syntax error in above code..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the error is (feel free to upload the code to a jsfiddle) but you could make it bullet-proof by being specific about max/min sizes for each media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
...
}
@media only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
...
}
@media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
...
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 769px) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ozke. That didn't seem to make a difference, but I did take your suggestion and try it on JSFiddle.  It worked there... so it's something about resizing in the browser that isn't working.  I've tried it in both Firefox and Chrome. Strange.